Why the T1 recovery & T2 decay are independent?
I was thinking that the decrease in transverse magnetization results in the recovery of longitudinal magnetization.
However, recently, I found it was wrong. I saw a diagram

(McRobbie 2014. Fundamentals of MR Imaging)
and also saw many writings saying "T1 and T2 relaxation are independent."
How is it possible? Where does the power emitted(?) from T2 decay go to?
(and also, all the animations I saw expressed them as dependent on each other.)

What is the source of the diagram? Using someone else's artwork without attribution is a violation of copyright law and SE policy. So please edit your question and add a link to the source.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/saturation-recovery
oh sorry here!

Thank you, but it needs to be in the question, not in a comment. Please [edit] the question to add it.

Science Direct is not a source. It's a publisher's search engine. I've edited the question to cite the actual source.

I think this is reasonably on-topic here, but you may be better off asking in a place where you find physicists rather than a place where you find medical professionals, as this has very little to do with what a physician would use an MRI for and much more to do with the physics of magnetism.

I’m voting to close this question because it has been reposted at: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/820213/

They are (mostly) independent of each other.
In a greatly simplified way, an MRI scan involves using a strong magnetic field to align the hydrogen atoms within the body. A radiofrequency pulse is then used to tip them over by 90⁰; initially they will all be aligned. Over time, each atom will rotate at a slightly different rate depending on the tissues it is in – this process changes them from being in phase to being uncorrelated, and the time it takes to occur is the T2 relaxation time. At a slower rate, they also tip back in to alignment with the magnetic field, and the rate at which this occurs is the T1 relaxation. These occur independently of each other and give different information – comparing T1 and T2 relaxation times is one of the ways in which MRI scans give information about the nature of the tissue being scanned.
In practice these are all statistical representations of the real world – you don’t get every single spin aligning, but enough of them do to give a measurable signal.
Radiopaedia covers this but it is a fairly complex area of physics. The full explanation requires a fair bit of maths but the principles can be explained without it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?si=rT709WNo7o7-3l6K&v=Vnqsrg4cUo4
